# How do I select the next highest ID?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that calculates the time taken to achieve an outcome. So for example where a case has a code of 'CB' the procedure should then look in table EVENTS to find the next time that one of a set of outcome codes is applied and use the DATE_CREATED value to set the value for CB_DATE. The case may have multiple codes but I am only interested in the first use after the CB code: Example table is below:

```
ID   CASE_ID DATE_CREATED    DATE_MODIFIED    OUTCOME_CODE  CB_DATE    
1     01      01/04/1970      01/04/1970      CASE_START
2     01      01/04/1970      02/04/1970      CB
3     01      01/04/1970      03/04/1970      PPLF
4     02      01/04/1970      02/04/1970      TEST
4     01      01/04/1970      04/04/1970      SACM
5     01      01/04/1970      05/04/1970      TEST         05/04/1970
6     01      01/04/1970      06/04/1970      OUTC
```

So I want to return the DATE_MODIFIED for the next entry after 'CB' where the code is in ('OUTC','TEST') which in the example above would be the second instance of 'TEST' as the first instance applies to a different CASE_ID.

Currently it is applying the procedure to every instance of the set of outcome codes as in my example above both instances of TEST and OUTC get a CB_DATE value but I just want TEST to have the value where CASE_ID matches the CASE_ID for the 'CB' outcome.

The current code is:
    update EVENTS e
    set    CB_DATE=DATE_MODIFIED
    where  OUTCOME_CODE in ('TEST','OUTC'....)

I had thought that I could use

```
  update   EVENTS e
  set      CB_DATE=DATE_MODIFIED
  WHERE    OUTCOME_CODE in ('TEST','OUTC'....)
  AND      ID > (
    select ID
    from   EVENTS x
    where  x.OUTCOME_CODE = 'CB'
    and    x.CASE_ID=e.CASE_ID);
```

Comment: ... and id > ( select max(id) from events x where ..)

Comment: it is not always the max(id) however, multiple codes could be used i want the next highest ID, for example ID 7 in the above table may have an outcome code of TEST for CASE_ID 01 too. I need to ensure it selects the first instance of the code.

Comment: ... and id > ( select max(id) from events x where x.id < e.id and x.outcome_code='CB' and x.case_id=e.case_id)

Comment: If you have id 7 case_id 01 code TEST, should be this updated or only first one (id 5) should be updated?

Comment: only first insatnce, so ID 5, should be updated

Answer (score 1):

It is may be not optimal but:

```
UPDATE tt e
   SET CB_DATE = DATE_MODIFIED
 WHERE OUTCOME_CODE IN ('TEST', 'OUTC')
   AND id > (SELECT MAX (id)
               FROM tt x
              WHERE x.id < e.id AND x.outcome_code = 'CB' AND x.case_id = e.case_id)
   AND NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM tt y
            WHERE y.id < e.id
              AND y.OUTCOME_CODE IN ('TEST', 'OUTC')
              AND y.case_id = e.case_id
              AND y.id > (SELECT MAX (id)
                            FROM tt x
                           WHERE x.id < e.id AND x.outcome_code = 'CB' AND x.case_id = e.case_id))
```

Other way is to get the CB ranges:

```
SELECT id, LEAD (id, 1, 99999999999999) OVER (PARTITION BY case_id ORDER BY id) next_id, case_id
  FROM tt
 WHERE outcome_code = 'CB'
```

And get the record with min ID where code is ('TEST' ,'OUTC')

```
UPDATE tt e
   SET CB_DATE = DATE_MODIFIED
 WHERE OUTCOME_CODE IN ('TEST', 'OUTC')
   AND (id, case_id) IN 
      (SELECT (SELECT MIN (id)
                FROM tt
               WHERE OUTCOME_CODE IN ('TEST', 'OUTC') AND id BETWEEN cbs.id AND cbs.next_id AND case_id = cbs.case_id) test_id,
             cbs.case_id
        FROM (SELECT id, LEAD (id, 1, 99999999999999) OVER (PARTITION BY case_id ORDER BY id) next_id, case_id
                FROM tt
               WHERE outcome_code = 'CB') cbs)
```

Change tt with events.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this all wrong. Instead of the MAX(ID) I need to look for the MIN(ID) where it is > than the current ID.

Essentially I was trying to get the next highest ID, which will be the MIN(ID) where the other conditions are met, i.e > than existing ID, where CASE_ID matches and where the OUTCOME_CODE is in the relevant group.

e.g

```
   update   EVENTS e
   set      CB_DATE=DATE_MODIFIED
   WHERE    OUTCOME_CODE in ('TEST','OUTC'....)
   AND      MIN(ID) > (
        select ID
        from   EVENTS x
        where  x.OUTCOME_CODE = 'CB'
        and    x.CASE_ID=e.CASE_ID);
```